# Can't delete module from VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-project

I have a problem updating certain modules. In some modules I can delete and import the modules, but on others what happens is that the module is imported first and the original deleted later which adds a `1` at the end of the module name and messes up the code.

**Here's how I do it:**
I have the following Excel file which I can track who needs or has updated to the new module version. When I update the module version I just type on the correct username column `Not Updated`. Once the user opens his MS Project it runs the following code and changes the value to `Updated`.
[image]

Then I run the following on Project.Activate in VBA - MS Project 2016 to check if the module needs to update.

```
Dim xlapp As Object
Dim xlbook As Object
Dim sHostName As String
Dim modulesList_loc As String
Dim projectVBA_loc As String
Dim modulesVBA_loc As String

projectVBA_loc = "\\sharedNetwork\Project\VBA\"
modulesVBA_loc = projectVBA_loc & "Modules\"
modulesList_loc = projectVBA_loc & "Modules Updates.xlsx"

' Get Host Name / Get Computer Name
sHostName = Environ$("username")

Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
SetAttr modulesList_loc, vbNormal
Set xlbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(modulesList_loc)


Dim rng_modules As Range
Dim rng_usernames As Range
Dim username As Range
Dim atualizado As Range
Dim module_name As Range
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim lastcol_letter As String
Dim linha As Integer
Dim len1 As Integer
Dim len2 As Integer
Dim module_name_short As String
Dim actualizar As Integer

'LAST USERNAME COLUMN
With xlbook.Worksheets(1)
    'Last Column
    lastcol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastcol_letter = GetColumnLetter(lastcol, xlbook.Worksheets(1))
End With

'Usernames range
Set rng_usernames = xlbook.Worksheets(1).Range("E2:" & lastcol_letter & "2")
'Finds the correct username
Set username = rng_usernames.Find(sHostName)

Set rng_modules = xlbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A3")  'First module
Do While rng_modules.Value <> Empty
    'Adds module if necessary
    linha = rng_modules.Row
    Set atualizado = username.Offset(linha - 2)
    Set module_name = rng_modules.Offset(, 1)
    If atualizado.Value = "Not Updated" Then
        With ThisProject.VBProject
            len1 = Len(module_name.Value)
            len2 = len1 - 4
            module_name_short = Left(module_name.Value, len2)
            On Error Resume Next
            .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents(module_name_short)
            .VBComponents.import modulesVBA_loc & module_name.Value
        End With
        atualizado.Value = "Updated"
    End If
    Set rng_modules = rng_modules.Offset(1)
Loop

xlbook.Close (True)
SetAttr modulesList_loc, vbReadOnly
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `DoEvents` after the `Remove` method is called to give time for the Remove method to complete.

```
'On Error Resume Next
.VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents(module_name_short)
DoEvents
.VBComponents.import modulesVBA_loc & module_name.Value
```

If the `Remove` method is failing, there is likely an error occurring, but the `On Error Resume Next` line is hiding the error. Comment out the `On Error...` line and see what the error is and handle it rather than ignore it.